# It is possible to connect two android wear emulators with one device?

Tags: android, android-emulator, wear-os

I'm building an app for android wear and I would like to test it on both round and square watch emulator, but so far I'm able to connect only one emulator with device via usb. You can imagine, how annoying is start one emulator then close it and start another one and all over again. And we all know how fast these emulator is starting.

Thanks.